# Using L2CAP Channel with CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, l2cap

I need to use L2CAP Channel with CoreBluetooth.
Therefore I will have to implement the StreamDelegate protocol and make a first test of sending one message from a sending app to a listening app.

Is there any good tutorial that I could follow for that. Up to this point the information I have found is too general.

Of course I have looked at the WWDC 2017 video:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/712/.

But I would like to find basic sample (with code) to get started.

I already started to write something ([CoreBluetooth / L2CAP channels, not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142326/corebluetooth-l2cap-channels-not-working)),
but it is not yet working.

Any tip or feedback, from someone who has already done that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try the following
https://github.com/github-deden/iOS_L2Cap in objc
https://github.com/paulw11/L2Cap in swift